# Postdoc salary in France

Tags: postdocs, salary, france

I am currently considering a postdoc position in France which would be funded by an ERC grant. Since it is the hosting institution to determine the salary I was wondering whether there are some fixed rules for a postdoc salary and, if so, where I can find them.

If not, how would the salary be determined? Is it an entirely negotiable amount? Is there a minimum salary that should be paid?